# How to align text center in Text.rich()

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using a text span widget in which I like to center all the text, instead of default alignment at the start.

```
 Text.rich(
                          TextSpan(
                            text: "Go to your e-mail inbox and ",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: appBackground_color,
                                fontSize: 14,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                            children: <InlineSpan>[
                              TextSpan(
                                text: "activate your account",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                  color: appBackground_color,
                                ),
                              ),
                              TextSpan(
                                text: " to proceed.",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                    color: appBackground_color),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
```

How can i center the text in this widget?

Comment: Did you try to pass ```textAlign: TextAlign.center``` to your ```Text.rich()``` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `RichText()` instead of `Text.rich()`. `Text.rich()` has no `textAlign` parameter. Use like this:

```
RichText(
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          text: TextSpan(
            text: "Go to your e-mail inbox and ",
            children: <InlineSpan>[
              TextSpan(),
              TextSpan(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

**But** remember, `RichText()` must have a width for the `textAlign` to work. Like this:

```
 Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              child: RichText(
               //**
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: As for today, ```Text.rich()``` has ```textAlign``` parameter. It still needs width to work